# grepl excluding a set of words before pattern

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I would like to capture all mentions of "pensions" (capital-insensitive, including pensions, pensioners, but excluding unrelated words like "suspension." However, I would like to exclude pensions when they are preceded by "Department of Work and "; but I can't manage to capture the whole expression. So far I have:

```
sentences <- c("department of work and pensions", "and pensioners", "pensioners", "Pensions", "suspension")
try <- grepl("(?<!department of work and )^pension*", ignore.case = T, perl = T, sentences)
try
```

Any advice?

Comment: Using a reserved word like `try` as a variable name is not recommended. Use some other name.

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
grepl("\\bpension\\S+", sentences, ignore.case = TRUE) & 
      !grepl("department of work .*\\bpension\\S+", sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep('(?<!department of work and )\\bpension', sentences, 
        value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)

[1] "and pensioners" "pensioners"     "Pensions"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single pattern that will account for any whitespaces between the words and also match `pension` only at the word boundary:

```r
sentences <- c("department of work and pensions", "and pensioners", "pensioners", "Pensions", "suspension")
grepl("\\bdepartment of work and \\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\bpension", ignore.case = T, perl = T, sentences)
## => [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/IUVrL1) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uKIXxw/1).

*Details*:

- `\bdepartment of work and \w+` - word boundary `\b`, `department of work and` + space + one or more word chars
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omit all text matched so far and start the next match search from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\bpension` - word boundary `\b` and a `pension` substring.

Comment: Incredible, thanks so much for the thorough explanation!